# A project that has to be release in multiple configurations

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, semantic-release

I'm a DevOps engineer for multiple teams with different projects.
One of the projects is one that deploys a single project to some of our teams. But every team needs a different configurations and some unique features which other teams don't need, or even worse, needs them to not exist.

I'm trying to implement Semantic Release for that project and it's proving difficult.
I need this one repo to publish different kind of versions for every team.
For example, teamA-v1.1.0, teamB-2.0.0.
Iv'e thought of some solutions like have major versions represent each team.
Is there a plugin that helps me with that? Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You forgot to tell us two of the most important things: **(1)** What language/framework is used for the project? **(2)** What system is used for the build and deploy steps? Without such details there can only be answers that are either totally vague, or totally bad because they assume technology stacks that don't apply.

Comment: Sorry, The project is Java/Maven, and we're deploying using Jenkins CI.